# How to close WPF User Control window

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I have a question about closing a User Control Window.

In this application the main window will have a button to open the User control Window. In the User Control Window there are two buttons: one is to save and the other is to cancel. In the cancel click event, the user control alone needs to get closed and get back to the main window.

This code is closing the main window, too.

```
private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var mywindow = Window.GetWindow(this);
    mywindow.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you try:

```
private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var mywindow = Window.GetWindow(this);
        this.Close();
    }
```

I guess **mywindow** is your main window